# Garbled characters in Eclipse/Spring Tool Suite UI

Tags: spring, eclipse

Garbled characters in Eclipse/Spring Tool Suite UI. Java class names, package names, class names, etc. All look garbled. I've tried to change preferences->Workspace->General Text file encoding (UTF, Cp1252, etc.) but nothing fixes the garbled names in the User Interface (Eclipse/STS itself).

[Garbled characters in Eclipse/STS UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE3ff.jpg)

Comment: Did you copy those classes etc from somewhere? If yes, from where? Like from some .doc/.xlsx etc file(s)?

Comment: No they are my own package/class names etc. that (after a Windows update) weren't readable anymore. I got an answer on The Eclipse forum that pointed me in the right direction:  I found that Unchecking "Use mixed fonts and colors for labels" in Window-Preferences->Gereral->Apearance makes the package -, class names, etc. readable. It isn't what it used to be and I guess what it's supposed to be but it's workable again.

Comment: what language your machine is using? English? Other than binary :-) If english, is it possible that you update your STS/Eclipse to the latest version?

Comment: It uses English and Dutch, I have STS 4.7.0 (and previous versions) and the latest Eclipse (2020-06) installed. All the names I use are English. In the "Colors and Fonts" preference page (that's what the Eclipse documentation calls it), font "Segoe UI" is used. That's the default and shouldn't cause issues. I still don't know what does.